# Как сделать сброс кликов по достижении числа 100, a потом увеличить число 100 до 1000?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Хочу добавить в свою игру уровни по количеству кликов (чтобы достичь *2* уровень, нужно *100* кликов, *3* уровень - *1000* кликов и т.д.).

Мне нужно, чтобы при достижении нового уровня клики сбрасывались, а их нужное количество увеличивалось.

Код:

```
void Update()
{
    if(click >= 100)
    {
        click = 0;
        CounterText.text = "1000";
    }
    if(click >= 1000)
    {
        click = 0;
        CounterText.text = "2000";
    }
}
```

Comment: сами то пробовали сделать?

Comment: Или нам игру всю таким макаром за вас сделать?))))

Comment: да, в методе Update через условие, но не получалось должным образом

Comment: Что именно у Вас не получается? Что уже пробовали? Если ничего не пробовали - начните с книг по C# >_<

Comment: сейчас напишу, что пробовал

Comment: извините, конечно, за такой вопрос, я новичок в этой сфере и в большинстве непонятных ситуаций разбираюсь сам, но с такой простой, на вид, задачей, не могу справиться.

Comment: я понимаю, что написал, знаю, какие есть ошибки, но не понимаю, как мне преобразовать свой код, чтобы все получилось

Comment: Представляете если у вас будет тысяча уровней что с этим кодом станет?)

Comment: ну а как быть?)

Comment: Подумать, запилить пару классов. Почитать. Поэксперементировать. Мы, конечно, можем сделать за вас, но вам от этой никакой пользы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как бы это сделал я. Заведем структуру `Level` где у нас будет хранится инфа про уровень, просто для удобства.

```
public struct Level
{
    public int LevelNumber { get; }
    public long Capacity { get; }

    public Level(int levelNumber, long capacity)
    {
        LevelNumber = levelNumber;
        Capacity = capacity;
    }
}
```

Потом такой вот класс-сервис, который будет заниматься у нас отслеживанием прогрессии.

```
public class LevelService
{
    private readonly List<Level> _levelList;
    private int _currentLevelIndex;
    private long _clickCount;

    public event Action<Level> OnNewLevel; //событие будет уведомлять нашу игру что уровень был достигнут

    public Level CurrentLevel => _levelList[_currentLevelIndex];

    public long ClickCount
    {
        get => _clickCount;

        private set //клики нельзя изменить извне класса, а следовательно мы спокойны
        {

            //если количество кликов будет выше текущей емкости уровня
            if (value >= CurrentLevel.Capacity)
            {
                _clickCount = 0; // обнуляем клики
                _currentLevelIndex++; //сдвигаемся на следующий уровень
                OnNewLevel?.Invoke(CurrentLevel); //уведомляем всех интересующихся
            }
            else
            {
                _clickCount = value; //просто увеличиваем клики.
            }
        }
    }

    //Здесь мы просто на вход принимаем последовательность 100 200 300 
    //или сколько вы там настроите - по хорошему брать эти значения из
    //конфига, такие штуки не должны быть захардкожены
    public LevelService(IEnumerable<int> levelList)
    {
        //и оборачиваем их в нашу структуру Level
        _levelList = levelList
            .Select((x, i) => new Level(i + 1, x))
            .ToList();
    }

    public void Click() => ClickCount++;
}
```

Где-нибудь в скрипте его объявлем:

```
var LevelManager = new LevelService(new List<int> { 100, 200, 500 });

//подписываемся на событие
LevelManager.OnNewLevel += (level) => { UpdateUi(level); }; //Там функция которая будет обновлять интерфейс игры
```

Когда клик случится просто дергаете

```
LevelManager.Click();
```

Код нужно доработать, я его так по быстрому накидал. Что бы было понятно общее направление мысли.

Comment: Ого, благодарю за пищу для размышлений!

Comment: Вся ваша благодарность может выразится в плюсиках и принятых ответах)

Comment: За такой ответ любого плюсика не жалко.